# jQuery .load function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using a simple .load() function from Jquery and I can't seem to make it work. Nothing happens when I click my DIV. My alert TEST does work.

```
<div class="ing">CLICK HERE</div>
<div id="overlay3-content"></div>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

   $(document).on('click', '.ing', function(e){
      $("#overlay3-content").load('content.html');
    // window.alert("test");  THIS WORKS
    });

</script>
```

the page content.html just has the following:

```
<html>TEST TEST TEST</html>
```

JS FIDDLE:  https://jsfiddle.net/37ukdrLf/

Any ideas

Comment: It works alright to me, except that content.html isnt found. I see an error in the network log on developer tools.  It tries to load content.html but the file isnt found. You might want to check the location of the content.html

Comment: @Sreekanth the content.html file is not correct ont he JS fiddle, but I am developping on my machine and the content.html is there, on the same folder as the code above

Comment: The file will be loaded relative to the path of the _page_. That means you either need to put it in the same folder as the page or adjust the path string accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are loading the model using either file:// or C:/, which stays true to the error message as they are not http://

So you can either install a webserver in your local PC or upload the model somewhere else and use jsonp and change the url to http://example.com/path/to/model

Answer taken from 
[HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10752055/cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-http-error-when-loading-a-local)

Comment: ahhh, you're right... I tried it on a server and it works... I didn't know it couldn't work on my machine. thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.ing', function(e){  
      $( "#overlay3-content" ).load( "content.html", function() {
        alert( "Load was performed." );
      });  
    });
```

Comment: @Sreekanth  I have just the HTML tag, and I tried with the body tag.  Like this;  <html><body>aaaaaaa</body></html>